# Teams tab does not update its content even though it has been changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating a teams tab addon. I just created the project using yeoman, teams creator. Now the problem I have is that after I execute the command gulp serve, the project is served and is openable, but it does not render new content even after changing it. It is always in the state of a project at its starting point.

Here is my Tab component (as you can see there is an empty div in the return method):

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Provider,
  Flex,
  Text,
  Button,
  Header,
} from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useTeams } from "msteams-react-base-component";
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
import axios from "axios";
import { HttpClient } from "../httpClient";

/**
 * Implementation of the Teams Demo Tab content page
 */
export const TeamsDemoTab = () => {
  const [{ inTeams, theme, context }] = useTeams();
  const [entityId, setEntityId] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>();
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
    if (inTeams === true) {
      microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
        successCallback: (token: string) => {
          const decoded: { [key: string]: any } = jwtDecode(token) as {
            [key: string]: any;
          };
          setName(decoded!.name);

          const serviceRequest: any = {
           [hidden for privacy]
          };

          httpClient.ExchangeForOBOToken(serviceRequest).then((res) => {
            console.log("baba");
            console.log(res.access_token);

            const config = {
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${res.access_token}` },
            };

            axios
              .get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", config)
              .then(console.log)
              .catch(console.log);
          });
          microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess();
        },
        failureCallback: (message: string) => {
          setError(message);
          microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyFailure({
            reason: microsoftTeams.appInitialization.FailedReason.AuthFailed,
            message,
          });
        },
        resources: [process.env.TAB_APP_URI as string],
      });
    } else {
      setEntityId("Not in Microsoft Teams");
    }
  }, [inTeams]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (context) {
      setEntityId(context.entityId);
    }
  }, [context]);

  /**
   * The render() method to create the UI of the tab
   */
  return (
   <div></div>
  );
};
```

but it always is this:

[image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUf1Z.png)

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.11",
  "id": "{{APPLICATION_ID}}",
  "version": "{{VERSION}}",
  "packageName": "{{PACKAGE_NAME}}",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Vizibit",
    "websiteUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}",
    "privacyUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/tou.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Teams Demo",
    "full": "Teams Demo"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "TODO: add short description here",
    "full": "TODO: add full description here"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/teamsDemoTab/config.html?name={loginHint}&tenant={tid}&group={groupId}&theme={theme}",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "sharePointPreviewImage": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/assets/teamsDemoTab-preview.png",
      "supportedSharePointHosts": [
        "sharePointFullPage",
        "sharePointWebPart"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}"
  ],
  "showLoadingIndicator": true,
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "{{TAB_APP_ID}}",
    "resource": "{{TAB_APP_URI}}"
  }
}
```

In the browser I get this:

[browser error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX86D.png)

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?pivots=node-java-script
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: We are not able to open the image which you are share.